# Unable to register user - TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use searches.set() instead

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've set up my models, serializers and viewsets in my Django REST API to assign a search record to a particular user, and to associate all the relevant user's searches to their record in the User model. It was all working fine, but I'm now getting the TypeError error message (in the subject line of this question) when I try to create a new user. I've listed the relevant models, serializers and viewsets below. Please could anyone take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated.

**User serializer:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searches = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=SearchHistoryModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'searches')
        extra_kwargs = {'email': {
            'required': True,
            'validators': [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
        }}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

**User viewset:**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

**Search model:**

```
class SearchHistoryModel(models.Model):
    """
    Stores each user's search submission
    """
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='searches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cpu_component_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    cpu_subcomponent_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    motherboard_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    gpu_component_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    gpu_subcomponent_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    gpu_subcomponent_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ram_component_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    ram_component_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ssd_component_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    ssd_component_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    hdd_component_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    hdd_component_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    optical_drive_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Search'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Searches'
        ordering = ['owner', 'created_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}\'s search choices'.format(self.owner)
```

**Search serializer:**

```
class SearchHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes the user's search history data passed into the SearchHistoryModel
    Associates each search with the relevant user
    """
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = SearchHistoryModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'created_date', 'owner', 'cpu_component_name', 'cpu_subcomponent_name',
            'motherboard_name', 'gpu_component_name', 'gpu_subcomponent_name',
            'gpu_subcomponent_quantity', 'ram_component_name', 'ram_component_quantity',
            'ssd_component_name', 'ssd_component_quantity', 'hdd_component_name',
            'hdd_component_quantity', 'optical_drive_name'
        )
```

**Search viewset:**

```
class SearchHistoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SearchHistoryModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SearchHistorySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)`, `validated_data` contains a `searches` value which is an id.

But actually the ForeignKey is **in the other sense** : in `Searches` model, and to refer to a `User` instance, not the opposite.

To link a user to searches, it is not in `User` DB table that you write an id, but in `Searches` that you write a User `id`.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    (...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Extract the value from 'validated_data'
        search_ids = validated_data.pop('searches', None)

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)

        # Update existing search instances
        for search_id in search_ids:
           Search.objects.filter(id=search_id).update(owner=user)

        return user
```